# Undefined shows on reduce function

Tags: javascript

Here is my code

```
const filterByType = (target , ...element) => {
    return element.reduce((start , next) =>{
        if(typeof next === target){
            start.push(next)
        }
    } , [])
}
```

My goal is like when I pass in
`filterByType('number', 1,2,3,'ke')`
and the result is [1,2,3]

bu the error shows

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I know I can use filter function but I really want to try to use reduce function to solve it ;(
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: you have to return start in the function. that's if (...) { start.push(next): } return start; }, [])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `return start`

```js
const filterByType = (target , ...element) => {
    return element.reduce((start , next) =>{
    
        if(typeof next === target){
            start.push(next)
        }
        return start
    } , [])
}

console.log(filterByType('number', 1,2,3,'ke'))
```